# Being an integral domain is not a local property

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for an example of  a ring R which is not an integral domain but the localization of R at every maximal ideal is  an integral domain

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Some geometry can help: disconnected thing cannot be integral, but each component could be integral.  For example, two points would suffice.

Concretely, take $A = \mathbb C[x]/(x(x-1))$.  Two two maximal ideals are $(x)$ and $(x-1)$.  Localizing at any one of them gives $\mathbb C$, but $A$ is clearly not a domain.

In fact, this is the only kind of examples that one can give.  If $A$ is Noetherian, then $A$ is integral iff $A$ is stalk-locally integral and $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is connected.

Comment: It is such a shame how such a well-thought answer which - 1) gives geometric insight, - 2) gives a result, which states what further assumptions one needs to make it a local property - has less upvotes than a simple 'Ok $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is an example'-answer.

Comment: This is perhaps a simple question, but how does one show that the localizations at these maximal ideals are $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 6):

Take $A = \Bbb Z/(6)$. You can verify that $A$ has two maximal ideals; namely, $\mathfrak{m}_1 = 2\Bbb Z/(6)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_2 = 3\Bbb Z/(6)$. I leave it to you to check that
\begin{align*}
A_{\mathfrak{m}_1}&\cong\Bbb F_2,\\
A_{\mathfrak{m}_2}&\cong\Bbb F_3,
\end{align*}
both of which are integral domains.